# Where to get the dcm4chee-hsm-s3.jar from?

Tags: amazon-s3, hsm, dcm4che

I need to configure a near line storage for a dcm4chee server which contains some medical images. In order to do that It's required to have the **dcm4chee-hsm-s3.jar** file. It seems that this jar file has to be built out of the source. but I cannot find a working reference to the source. Can someone please help me to find the source?

Answer (score 1):

I use DCM4CHEE as a DICOM server (backend). DCM4CHEE has a web panel to configure and very rarely need to modify the source code, unless you have very specific requirements for your environment. What you need to do exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ale, I wanted to configure dcm4che server to use an Amazon s3 bucket as a nearline storage (as mentioned here http://www.dcm4che.org/confluence/display/ee2/Using+Amazon+S3+for+NEARLINE+storage ). In order to do that it's required to have this HSM module (dcm4chee-hsm-s3.jar) wich bridges the dcm4che and amazon s3 bucket. I wanted to get that hsm module jar created out of the source code or get that pre-built jar file from somewhere available

Comment: DCM4CHEE site reads:

Version Info: FYI - This feature is only available by building the code from SVN right now. http://dcm4che.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dcm4che/dcm4chee/sandbox/dcm4chee-hsm-cloud/

I checked the link, and is broken, this sounds like the "feature" was not fully implemented.

Comment: Yes, I've experienced the same. Therefore I went to an alternative solution. I just hosted a dcm4che instance in amazon EC2 server (to which the images are being pushed for backups (nearline/online)) and I've mapped a amazon S3 bucket as a local heard drive to that EC2 Instance using amazon s3 fuse. Then I did nessasary configurations for nearline storage in dcm4che such that the images are being ".tar" ed and pushed in to the S3 bucket mapped as a local heard disk.

Comment: Hi @Asa Could you explain a little further how did you do it. By the way the link is working now but have no idea how to build the code. Any idea?